# Identifying whether a script has executed

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml

If a script tag is inserted using `HTMLElement.innerHTML` it's not executed.  Is there a way to identify, by looking at the HTMLScriptElement, that it has never been executed?

Longer context: a React app with server side rendering uses React's `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to inject dynamic content which may include `<script>` tags.  When server side rendered these scripts run, when client side rendered they do not.  I'd like to use lifecycle hooks to inspect execute the scripts client side *without* executing the ones that were executed due to server side rendering already.

Answer (score 0):

I found a React workaround that doesn't really address the basic question; instead of attempting to tell whether a given script element has actually been executed, I build a list of all scripts on page *before* the render method is called (in the component constructor) and then when recreating script elements I just ignore any that I have already seen the source for.

That lets me identify all of the scripts that were added by the render, because they weren't in the original set.

Still curious about the original question, as that would allow a more elegant fix.